# unquote a list in Clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros, quote

I try to define a macro to extract info from a special form of text, `[0 => "0\n"]`, actually a list in Clojure.

Now let's say I simply want to get the `first` part of it with macro `get-input`.

```
(println (get-input [0 => "0\n"])) ; i.e. 0
```

The one below works pretty well.

```
; this works
(defmacro get-input
  [expr]
  (let [input (first expr)]
    input))
```

But when I use **Syntax-Quote**, i.e., backquote, things are getting confusing.
Just unquoting the `expr` with `~` leads me to this.
While actually I never use the `second` part of the `expr`, i.e. `=>`, but seems it still get evaluated behind.

> CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: => in this context

```
; this sucks
(defmacro get-input
  [expr]
  `(let [input# (first ~expr)]
     input#))
```

I want to know what is the difference between first solution and the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro are expanded at compile time, and the body of the macro is evaluated. If it is syntax-quoted, only the unquoted expressions are evaluated, but if there are no quote (like in your first macro definition), the body is evaluated at compile time.

If you expand `(get-input [0 => "0\n"])` with your first definition (no quote), you will have

```
> (macroexpand '(get-input [0 => "0\n"]))
0
```

`0` is the result of the macro-expansion, meaning all calls to `(get-input [0 => "0\n"])` will be replace at compile time by `0`.

With the second definition the expansion will be something like (the generated symbol will be different)

```
> (macroexpand '(get-input [0 => "0\n"]))
(let* [input__11966__auto__ (first [0 => "0\n"])] 
  input__11966__auto__)
```

After expansion, the Clojure compiler will evaluate the vector `[0 => "0\n"]`, and as stated in the [clojure doc](http://clojure.org/evaluation) states:

> Vectors, Sets and Maps yield vectors and (hash) sets and maps whose contents are the *evaluated values* of the objects they contain.

Each element of the vector are evaluated in sequence, which is fine for `0` (evaluates to the number 0), but not for `=>` which is not a known symbol.

May be what you are looking for is to expand the expression (in your case the vector), *without* evaluation of its content. For this you need to `quote` the result of the `~`, e.g.

```
(defmacro get-input-as-str
  [expr]
  `(let [a# (quote ~expr)]
     (map str a#)))
```

which expand to - note the `'[...]`:

```
> (macroexpand '(get-input-as-str [0 => "0\n"]))
(let* [a__12040__auto__ '[0 => "0\n"]] (map str a__12040__auto__))
```

And gives

```
> (get-input-as-str [0 => "0\n"])
("0" "=>" "0\n")
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! By the way, ``(quote ~expr)`` can be simplified as ``'~expr``

Comment: Tkx, yes you are right, it was just to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this exception because you're trying to unquote `[0 => "0\n"]` form, which is not a valid Clojure code. You could fix it by changing an order of `first` and unquote operations:

```
(defmacro get-input
  [expr]
  `(let [input# ~(first expr)]
     input#))
```